# Nodejs and Gearman

Tags: node.js, gearman

Can we use Gearman with Nodejs, is that the right case ? As node js is it self a single thread and with Gearman we tried to make it multithreaded indirectly. Please suggest.

I have setup of Nodejs with Heroku.
Work Scenario:

- Need to write cronjob with nodejs which runs at every 10 sec and there are lots of them - 100000+ users.
- Fetch data for each user from third party api
- Update data in Mongodb.

Problem :

- Nodejs asynchronously run, so is it better to write Gearman for such scenario?
- Is there any better solution with Nodejs for such problem.
- Heroky default Dynos only support minimum 10 minutes cronjob (scheduler)
- I need to write it for every 10 sec... or maximum by 30 sec.
- How to write that with Heroku, how to setup?
- Clock.js is there but how to use that ?

Suggestion:

- Use Gearman with Nodejs

Kindly update with your valuable suggestion ASAP.